# Performance of chained public member access compared to pointer

Tags: c++, performance, chaining

Since I couldn't find any question relating to chained member access, but only chained function access, I would like to ask a couple of questions about it.

I have the following situation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < largeNumber; ++i)
{
  //do calculations with the same chained struct:
  //myStruct1.myStruct2.myStruct3.myStruct4.member1
  //myStruct1.myStruct2.myStruct3.myStruct4.member2
  //etc.
}
```

It is obviously possible to break this down using a pointer:

```
MyStruct4* myStruct4_pt = &myStruct1.myStruct2.myStruct3.myStruct4;
for(int i = 0; i < largeNumber; ++i)
{
  //do calculations with pointer:
  //(*myStruct4_pt).member1
  //(*myStruct4_pt).member2
  //etc.
}
```

Is there a difference between member access (.) and a function access that, e.g., returns a pointer to a private variable?

Will/Can the first example be optimized by the compiler and does that strongly depend on the compiler?

If no optimizations are done during compilation time, will/can the CPU optimize the behaviour (e.g. keeping it in the L1 cache)?

Does a chained member access make a difference at all in terms of performance, since variables are "wildly reassigned" during compilation time anyway?

I would kindly ask to leave discussions out regarding readability and maintainability of code, as the chained access is, for my purposes, clearer.

**Update:**
Everything is running in a single thread.

Comment: The compiler can't assume there are no other threads, so it has to reevaluate the first example every time. 2nd is better if there are no threads, but wrong if there are. Good case for the Pascal `with` keyword, if no threads.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your comment. But this re-evaluation is a compiler side performance issue, if I understand correctly?! Does that have any effect on the runtime performance? N.B. I do only use a single thread.

Comment: @EJP: OP uses member access(`.` not `->`), he doesn't deference pointer in the chain. so your comment doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a constant offset that you're modifying, a modern compiler will realize that.

But - don't trust me, lets ask a compiler (see [here](http://goo.gl/tdy2gc)).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct D { float _; int i; int j; };

struct C { double _; D d; };

struct B { char _; C c; };

struct A { int _; B b; };

int bar(int i);
int foo(int i);

void foo(A &a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a.b.c.d.i += bar(i);
    a.b.c.d.j += foo(i);
  }
}
```

Compiles to

```
foo(A&):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rdi, %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    subq    $8, %rsp
.L3:
    movl    %ebx, %edi
    call    bar(int)
    addl    %eax, 28(%rbp)
    movl    %ebx, %edi
    addl    $1, %ebx
    call    foo(int)
    addl    %eax, 32(%rbp)
    cmpl    $10, %ebx
    jne .L3
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

As you see, the chaining has been translated to a single offset in both cases: `28(%rbp)` and `32(%rbp)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and +1 for providing the compiling check! You say in your answer "modern" compiler. Do you know if there is a certain "compiler optimizing parameter" that I have to look out for, for this to happen?

Comment: Note that your chain does not contain function calls or pointers. This means that the compiler can calculate the exact position of the chained variable relative to the position of the object at the beginning of the chain at compile time. Any compiler should to this when folding, the first optimization level will suffice for this to happen.

Comment: A last question in this regard. Can your example still hold, if there is some member in either of the structs of variable length, e.g., std::vector. And possibly, what if one of the structs is actually inside this vector, so that I would have to access: `myStruct1.myStruct2[index].myStruct3.my...`

Comment: A struct does not have variable length, even if it contains `std::vector`. The allocation for the vector is somewhere else. The length of a struct is fixed (except if you use C99 flexible array members, which you presumably don't). To answer your question: Once the address you're writing to is not constant anymore, the compiler might not reduce the address calculation as well anymore (i.e. not a single instruction anymore). Feel free to use a reference or a pointer there, and measure if you get any improvement (probably minor).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.